# Encrypt HLS fregment using openssl issue

Tags: openssl, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a regulat HLS fregments and I want to encrypt them using `Openssl` to be AES-128 clearKEy encrypted.

My approach was:

1. Getting the HLS (In our production I get already mafe HLS file, I have no control on the creation of that) - the HLS fregments are `.mp4` and not `.ts`.
2. Run the command: `find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in {} -out {}.enc -p -nosalt -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -K 97979797979797979797979797979797 \; -exec  mv {}.enc {} \;` - to encrypt all the fregments with `IV` 0 and key `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`.
3. Edit the .m3u8 file and add to them the line: `#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://www.myKeyServer.com/key.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000` .
4. Try to run this in `https://hlsjs.video-dev.org/demo/`.

When I try the 4th stage, I get errors like:

```
Failed to find demuxer by probing fragment data, audio_und_2c_128k_aac_1.mp4
```

My `https://www.myKeyServer.com/key.key` response is:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

When I tried it on other player `https://bitmovin.com/demos/drm` I get the error: `ERROR_DECRYPTING`.

What do I do rung here (in the encryption process or the decryption process)?

----- edit ----

I try encrypt using the following script as well:

```
mport os
import subprocess

ENC_KEY = f"{ord('a')}"*16
print (ENC_KEY)

# Loop through all .mp4 files in the current directory
video_files = []
audio_files = []
for file in os.listdir():
        if not file.endswith(".mp4"):
                continue

        if "audio" in file:
                audio_files.append(file)

        if "video" in file:
                video_files.append(file)

video_files.sort()
audio_files.sort()

i = 0
iv = f"{i:032x}"

print ("video_files:", video_files)
print ("audio_files:", audio_files)

# Encrypt the init
def init_enc(files, iv):
    for f_name in files:
        if not "init" in f_name:
            continue
        orig = os.path.join("/app/tstEncription/output_files", f_name)
        enc = os.path.join("/app/tstEncription/output_files", f_name + "_enc")
        print (enc)
        subprocess.run(["openssl", "aes-128-cbc", "-e", "-in", orig,  "-out", enc, "-nosalt", "-iv", iv, "-K", ENC_KEY])

init_enc(video_files, iv)
init_enc(audio_files, iv)

def enc_files(files, _i):
    i = _i
    iv = f"{i:032x}"
    for f_name in files:
        if "init" in f_name:
            continue

        orig = os.path.join("/app/tstEncription/output_files", f_name)
        enc = os.path.join("/app/tstEncription/output_files", f_name + "_enc")
        print (enc)
        subprocess.run(["openssl", "aes-128-cbc", "-e", "-in", orig, "-out", enc, "-nosalt",  "-iv", iv, "-K", ENC_KEY])

        i = i + 1
        iv = f"{i:032x}"

enc_files(video_files, 1)
enc_files(audio_files, 1)
```

still no luck

Comment: `AES-128` and `ClearKey` are 2 different things, from the content you probably mean to `AES-128`.